# How to validate a model when the data is highly imbalanced?

Tags: cross-validation, unbalanced-classes

My data is highly skewed with about 1% positive cases and 99% negative cases.

How can I validate a machine learning model like a random forest on this data?

Naturally, I prefer 10-fold cross validation but that does not work because some folds will always contain only negative cases. Is there a way arround that? Stratified 100-fold cross validation might work but also introduces a lot of variance.

Answer (score -1):

In your shoes instead of struggling to evaluate the model you built with the imbalanced data, I would use some of the following techniques during training in order to result in a model that can be evaluated easily with the techniques you mentioned. You won't have problem evaluating as your "new" data will be balanced.
Namely you can read about these:

- Undersampling
- Oversampling
- Synthetic Data Generation
- Cost Sensitive Learning

There are many sources online for more information like this one: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/practical-guide-deal-imbalanced-classification-problems/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as far as I know you usually validate on unsampled data which is why your answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: If you have to throw away data to make a method work the method is defective.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there are two problems with measuring of the quality of classificator if classes are highly imbalanced.

First - how to do cross-validation in a right way. I suggest you to use stratification: we split the whole sample in such a way that share of minor class is similar for training and test sample (i.e. if we have a sample of 1000 points with 10 minor class examples, then if we split 70% / 30% we always put 3 minor class object to the test sample and 7 to the training sample). It is not the best way, but all other approaches will also have high variance as we can't avoid high variance related to strange distributions of minr class objects between the training sample and the test sample.

Second - you need to use correct quality measure, as the common ROC AUC or accuracy don't work well, as they focuses on overall performance, while we expect to find how well the model is in identification of minor class objects. So, use F1-score instead, that is a combination of precision and recall that capture most of the effect you are typically required to observe.

Comment: I doubt that F1 is a proper scoring rule.  Use a continuous proper probability accuracy score, e.g., scaled log likelihood or Brier score.  And the bootstrap will avoid the "zero positives in a sample" problem.

Comment: I don't think that Brier score is a good idea (at least there are no evidence regarding that it is good if we look in Machine learning community). The second comment is also more appropriate to Statistics than to Machine learning (I don't understand how can bootstrap fight small number of objects that fall into the test sample, leading to poor cross validation score).

Comment: These ideas were invented in the statistics community, not the ML community, and have been around since long before ML existed.  If you want to have a chance that the derived predictive instrument is correct you need to use a proper accuracy score.  Brier works well.  The likelihood function even better.  The bootstrap works because any one bootstrap sample will contain about 0.63 of the original observations, so the chance of not selecting any observations with Y=1 is very small.  You can also do a balanced bootstrap if really needed.  Bootstrap is also more precise than CV.